# Editing files in debian before installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, editors

I am having problems installing debian on virtualbox. The installation step fails when trying to configure packet manager.

The guy in the following post had them solved by editing a certain file during one of the installation phases.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/146574/configuring-the-package-manage-failed-installation-on-11-10?newreg=3029c47198d34bb7be96025ffe0b3e32

I am completely new to Linux, command lines in general and have no idea how to: "Edit /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/50mirror.ubuntu and comment out the two lines with db_metaget and db_subst statements after the comment "Text is variable for Debian"."

could someone show some basic commands that would do it? :) I've already navigated to /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/ and found the 50mirror file.

How should I proceed?
How do I close the shell and return to the installation afterwards?

UPDATE:
for anyone, trying to install linux on VirtualBox, install VirtualBox using administrator privileges. Then launch it with them as well. Worked for me :)

Comment: Please tell us what problem you are attempting to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to edit a file from the terminal for a beginner is to use `nano`.

To start nano and open a file:

```
nano path/to/file
```

When you are in `nano`, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get help, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano. These are listed at the bottom of the screen but with the `^` character for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

This [beginner's guide to nano](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/) might be helpful.

You can get back to the main install process by pressing <kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks :) Nano is just what I needed. Although alt-F7 doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `Ctrl+Alt+F7`. Have edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: That didn't work as well. Although I've decided to try all alt-F* combinations and alt-F1 returned me to the installations screen, which is what I needed.
Thanks for the help :) P.S. this didn't solve my installation problem though ^^

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of a normal running system.  Thanks for reporting what worked. Install error messages and logs are redirected to the fourth console. You can access this console by pressing `Left Alt+F4`. Maybe looking at that might give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the words `db_metaget` and `db_subst` present only on the lines which you want to comment out. Now try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/\(.*db_metaget.*\)/#\1/g' /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/50mirror.ubuntu"
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/\(.*db_subst.*\)/#\1/g' /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/50mirror.ubuntu"
```